# cant get concat values and php not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, momentjs

So my problem is that why `jquery` concat is not working and also it is not posting and can't inserted into the `database`

I tried changing the code and read references still cant get enough

This is my **jquery**

```
    var uid = $('#lname').val() + $('fname').val() + $('#datecreated').val(moment().format('YYYY')); 
    var datecreated = $('#datecreated').val(moment().format('YYYY'));
    var fname = $('#fname').val();
    var lname = $('#lname').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#pass').val();
    var passcheck = false;
```

This is my **ajax**

```
    if (uid && fname && lname && email && password && datecreated)
                    {
                        var form = $(this);
                        var formData = new FormData(this);
                        $(".formcontent").hide();
                        $.ajax({
                          url : form.attr('action'),
                          type: form.attr('method'),
                          data: form.serialize(),
                          data: formData,
                          dataType: 'json',
                          cache: false,
                          contentType: false,
                          processData: false,
                          success:function(response)
                          {
```

this is my  full code **php**, I dunno if the problem is with **xampp** or not. Im tackling this problem for 3 day straight now and I dunno where the problem is

```
    valid['success'] = array('success' => true, 'messages' => array());
    $uid = $_POST ['uid'];
    $pass  =  $_POST['pass'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $datecreated = $_POST['datecreated'];
        if ($_POST)
    {
        if(true)
        {
            $sqlmail = "SELECT * FROM acc WHERE (email = '$email') AND acc_stat < 3";
            $resmail = $connect->query($sqlmail);
            if($resmail->num_rows > 0) 
            {
                while($row = $resmail->fetch_array())
                {
                    if($email === $row['email'])
                    {
                        $valid['messages'] = "Email address is already taken";
                    }

                }
                $valid['success'] = false;
                $connect->close();
                echo json_encode($valid);
            }
            else
            {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO 'acc' ('uid', 'password', 'lname', 'fname', 'email', 'acc_type', 'acc_stat','date_create')  VALUES ('$uid', '$pass', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '3', '1','$datecreated')";

                if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) 
                {
                    $valid['success'] = true;
                    $valid['messages'] = "Account registration successful.";                
                    $connect->close();
                    echo json_encode($valid);
                }
                else 
                {
                    $valid['success'] = false;
                    $valid['messages'] = "Network connection not stable. Please try again later.";
                    $connect->close();
                    echo json_encode($valid);       
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            $valid['success'] = false;
            $valid['messages'] = "No internet connection.";
            $connect->close();
            echo json_encode($valid);   
        }
    }
```

Comment: correct `$('fname').val()` to `$('#fname').val()` in first line of js please and try again

Comment: @KiranManiya ooh thankyou

Comment: finally worked?

Comment: @KiranManiya still not tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small mistake in your code, please fix it and it should work fine. the error is at line

`var uid = $('#lname').val() + $('fname').val() + $('#datecreated').val(moment().format('YYYY'));`

chage it to `var uid = $('#lname').val() + $('#fname').val() + $('#datecreated').val(moment().format('YYYY'));`.

silly mistake of missing just `#`. one more thing, you will not receive the `uid` paramter in php side, just because you are not sending it with form. append it to `FormData` as give,

```js
var uid = $('#lname').val() + $('#fname').val() + $('#datecreated').val(moment().format('YYYY'));.
var formData = new FormData(this);
formData.append('uid' , uid);
```

Now you will be able to recieve that `uid` parameter.

Comment: I already Fix it but its not working though, Its not inserting in the database

Comment: may i know the db query?

Comment: i posted my whole php and query

Comment: where is the form? you can git a try to https://www.w3resource.com/ajax/working-with-PHP-and-MySQL.php

Comment: this is my form

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
 var uid = $('#lname').val() + $('#fname').val() + $('#datecreated').val(moment().format('YYYY')); 
    var datecreated = $('#datecreated').val(moment().format('YYYY'));
    var fname = $('#fname').val();
    var lname = $('#lname').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#pass').val();
    var passcheck = false;
```